# C# Directory.Exists ipv6 version

Tags: c#, ipv6

I am using `Directory.Exists(uncPath)` with a UNC path, now it fails if I use the standard IPv6 address. Is there code available which can take care of all formats of unc - ipv4/ipv6/machiname.

Currently I convert my ipv6 address to something like `2001-0-234-c1ab-0-a0-aabc-3e.ipv6-literal.net` and it works, but Ipv6 itself can be represented in multiple formats. I need something which will handle all formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *ipv6-literal.net* notation is the only way to use an IPv6 UNC on windows.

You need to take your IPv6 litteral & replace `:` with `-`, `%` with `s` and append `ipv6-literal.net`.

Comment: I read somewhere that '% => s' is only necessary if you are using a link-local IPv6 address. Global Unicast and Unique Local addresses don’t require interface identifiers. What the heck is that? Does this mean there are some special cases?

Comment: I don't know if a scope id is valid in a UNC

Comment: Further info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_UNC_path_names